# What conjugation of what word is ぐろく?

Tags: translation

For the life of me I cannot track down the bolded word in Jisho. I expected it to be the adverbial form of an い-adjective, but ぐろい is not listed (just グロい, which seems wrong in the context).

> 空は青**ぐろく**、一面の星がまたたいていました。<- Excerpt from よだかの星

I don't like to ask for a single word to be translated like this... but since I can't even **find** it (or any possible dictionary forms like ぐろくる, ぐろい, etc) in a dictionary, I'm hoping there might be something more to learn here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「空{そら}は青{あお}ぐろく、一面{いちめん}の星{ほし}がまたたいていました。」

As you know (I hope), ***all verbs and adjectives conjugate in Japanese***, but only the dictionary forms can usually be found in the dictionary.  It is, therefore, imperative that one learn how verbs and adjectives conjugate even if it might be a pain in the you-know-where.  You will only thank yourself for mastering it because, frankly, there is no such thng as being even semi-fluent in Japanese if you cannot conjugate words freely.

「ぐろく」 is only part of the word 「青ぐろく」.

「青ぐろく」 is the 連用形{れんようけい} ("continuative form") of the adjective 「青ぐろい/青黒い」 ("bluish-black").

(Whenever you see an unfamiliar word placed ***mid-sentence***, think of the possibility of it being in the 連用形.  There have been quite a few questions about the 連用形 without the questioners realizing that they are the 連用形 of the verbs and adjectives that they have long been familiar with.)

Thus, the sentence means:

> "The sky was bluish-black ***and*** the stars all around were blinking."

**To say "and" is the function of the 連用形 here.  You state something and continue to say something else**.

Here is how the adjective 「青黒い」 conjugate.

青黒**かろ**（う）、青黒**かっ**（た）、青黒**く**/青黒**く**（ない）、青黒**い**、青黒**けれ**（ば）

The parts in **bold** above are the nitty-gritty and those are where mistakes are made by J-learners.

Finally, regarding the reason for the く-to-ぐ change in 「青ぐろい」, read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku).  The phenomenon is called 連濁{れんだく}.

Comment: "「ぐろく」 is only part of the word 「青ぐろく」". That's where I went wrong. I know how to conjugate to that form from 青ぐろい, but I didn't think that 青 was part of the word.

Answer (score 1):

青ぐろく is the continuative/adverbial form of 青黒い(so the ぐろく is only a part of the word)