# -く form for な-adjectives

Tags: て-form, adjectives, na-adjectives

My textbook (A course in modern Japanese, volume two) states the following (Lesson 11 p.26):

> In spoken language, sentences are connected with the て-form. And in written language, they are connected with the verb-base and く-form.

The book gives examples for verbs (行って -> 行き) and い-adjectives (高くて -> 高く), but I don't know how to handle な-adjectives.
The く-form doesn't appear in the conjugation tables I found in the book. Online, the く-form is mentionned in the case of adverbs, but I am not sure it is the same thing. For example, is the following transformation correct?

このかばんはきれいで,　やすい　->  このかばんはきれいに,　やすい　?

(I found
[this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57082/whats-the-difference-between-an-adjectives-adverbial-form-and-continuative-for), but it also only mentions い-adjectives)

Comment: The linked question has the exact answer, which is "No, there is no such form for な-adjectives". In my defense, it was hard to find if you don't know the form name in Japanese. Thanks a lot to the contributor who linked me to the other question!

Comment: don't worry, it's okay to produce duplicates from time to time, specially if you have tried to find the question before writing your own. When I read your post, I recalled that I had asked the same question in the past, but I had a hard time finding it too, even though it was my own question. Now, people who find your duplicate question will be redirected to it, so you have indeed contributed to increase its visibility. Thank you!