# what does the て form mean here?

Tags: grammar

In this sentence:
きっと、人生最後の日を前に思うのだろう
全部、全部言い足りなく**て**惜しいけど

In translation, it is "unspeakably regrettable", but is it really? wouldnt that be more like 言い足りないくらいに惜しい? or something? what does the て form do? If im incorrect, why?

Also is it possible to include your own translation after? i would like to see the difference.

Comment: It is the standard continuative usage - https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57082/45489 . So it is a mistranslation, strictly speaking.

Comment: What would the more correct translation look like?

Comment: Literally something like *(I) do not finish saying it all, and feel it's a pity*.